# Swift 3.0 is unsupported even though the project is set to Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

For some reason even though my project is set to Swift 5, when I try to build the Unit Tests it complains that Swift 3.0 is unsupported. I'm not sure why it thinks the project is using swift 3, when both the project and the pods project are set to Swift 5.

Any insights would be appreciated, I'm sure I've missed something basic.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked the swift version for all targets including the test target?

Comment: you also need to check one by one pod and test target swift version

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Thanks! That was the thing I was missing

Comment: Great that you solved this but I think you should remove this question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found, I overlooked the Test Target.